# How to modify WP Job Manager job listings template?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Long story short - where is the template for the listing list items that are shown when the [jobs] shortcode is used?

I have a WP site with WP Job Manager. I am using the [jobs] shortcode to show a list of the jobs that is searchable. I need to modify the template of the listings to show lets say an excerpt of the job offer. I think the template showing there is the content-job_listing.php, but when I modify it nothing happens. So my problem is I can't seem to find the correct template.

I've searched the whole plugin code and can't seem to find anything remote to what is displayed on my page where the [jobs] shortcode is.

So what is happening here you think and where usually is the template I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

content-job_listing.php ist the corect template for it. What theme are you using? If you are using a WP Job Manager specific theme like Jobify then they probably have a custom template overriding the plugin's template. Then you'd have to look in their documentation to see which file that is.

Where are you editing the file? In a child theme or in the plugin's folder? If you are editing the file in the plugin's folder and you don't see changes then you probably have the file in a child theme as well. The child theme takes priority in that case.

Anyway you should make changes only in a child theme and not in the plugin files to make sure your changes are update-proof. It could also be that you are editing the file in a child theme which is not the active theme in your WP install?

If you haven't done yet check out the official WPJM documentation on this topic: https://wpjobmanager.com/document/template-overrides/

Comment: This is solved now, after I spent some time to really learn how things are done in this plugin. So basically I inherited this project and the previous dev had made an overriding template as per the JobManagers docs. I was basically editing the one that was not used. Later I found the overriding template and edited it - it all worked fine.